# PIVOT one numeric column into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, transpose

Raw data:

```
ID  Age Date        Value
-------------------------
1   5   01/01/2023  10
1   5   01/04/2023  15
2   7   01/02/2023  17
3   9   10/02/2022  7
3   9   12/20/2022  9
```

Desired output:

1. One `ID/Age` per row (Age will always be the same per ID)
2. Use latest `Date` partitioned by ID if has multiple dates
3. Pivot the `Value` column into two separate columns, `Value_1` and `Value_2`
4. If an `ID` does not have 2nd value, in the output, leave `Value_2` blank
5. `Value_1` is the highest, `Value_2` is second highest

This is what the output should look like:

```
ID  Age Date        Value_1   Value_2
-------------------------------------
1   5   01/04/2023    15        10
2   7   01/02/2023    17    
3   9   12/20/2022     9         7
```

I couldn't figure it out even after reading the `PIVOT` reference. It is little bit different than the example I read over. The column I am pivoting is a numeric column, not categorical. I need some help here.
https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/pivot.php

**My attempt/some ideas**:

```
select *
from 
    (select 
         ID, Age, Date,
         Value,
         row_number() over (partition by ID order by Date desc) row_num
     from 
         table) a
where 
    a.row_num = 1


SELECT 
    ID, Age, Date, 'Value_1', 'Value_2'
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ID, Age, Date, Value
     FROM 
         table) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
    (SUM(Value)
     FOR Date IN ('day1', 'day2')
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

**Updates:** both @dale-k and @t-n's solution are good. If you have more than 2 values you can try @t-n's PIVOT approach. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `PIVOT` translates a set of column values around the values of a single nominated column (the "pivot"). Have you tried handling the `Age` and `Date` columns outside the `PIVOT`, such as by calculating their aggregate maximums in an `OUTER APPLY`?

Comment: Age is unique per ID, this question has nothing to do with Age.

Comment: `Age` and `Date` are both in your desired result set, so it affects how you structure the query.

Comment: @DaleK - Apologize for my previous tones, I am testing the query. Seems work perfectly I am doing some validation on the real data. Will update here shortly.

Comment: @DaleK your code seems not related to PIVOT as PIVOT function not used here, so do I interpret my initial question incorrectly?  How should I better explain this question?

Comment: Thats a difficult question actually, someone else might have a better idea, but I don't think calling this a PIVOT is wrong. However there a number of different ways to PIVOT data, and especially when you only want a small number of columns, the alternatives are often simpler than a proper PIVOT.

Comment: Can there be more than two values per ID? If so, should all but the two highest be discarded?

Comment: The real data I have have a filter only keep the highest two value, so in the original table that's maximum 2 rows per ID.  But yes technically, this question could expand to N different value and @TN 's code below may solve that puzzle. I haven't tested it, but will try soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query returns your desired results using standard aggregation with a case expression.

```
select
    ID
    , Age
    , max([Date]) [Date]
    , max([Value]) Value_1
    , case when min([Value]) <> max([Value]) then min([Value]) else null end Value_2
from @MyTable
group by ID, Age;
```

Returns:

| ID | Age | Date | Value_1 | Value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2023-01-04 | 15 | 10 |
| 2 | 7 | 2023-01-02 | 17 | NULL |
| 3 | 9 | 2022-12-20 | 9 | 7 |

Comment: Thanks. this works, when I applied to real data, I added one more case when statement for the scenario when an ID have same value in different date,  case when min([Value]) <> max([Value]) AND min([Date]) <> max([Date]) then min([Value])  else null end Value_2,  this will capture the second value (although it is same as first one).

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that uses ROW_NUMBER() and PIVOT and can be expanded to more than two Value columns, try:

```
SELECT PVT.ID, PVT.Age, PVT.Date,
    [1] AS Value_1, [2] AS Value_2
FROM (
    SELECT
        ID, Age, Value,
        MAX(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Age) AS Date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Age ORDER BY Value DESC) AS RN
    FROM @Data D
) Source
PIVOT (
    MAX(Source.Value)
    FOR Source.RN IN ([1], [2])
) PVT
ORDER BY PVT.ID, PVT.Age
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a7POeRrW).